# Enable only forward swiping in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` in which I am displaying a `UICollectionViewCell`. Each cell has the same `height` and `width` as the `collection view`.

I want to restrict the user to swipe back to the `UICollectionViewCell` after they have proceeded to the next cell

Something like a tinder experience, Although I have `Pagination enabled` in my `UICollectionView`

Comment: you can try delegate method of collectionView \**"func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)"**/

Answer (score 3):

**You can do this with following steps**

You have to get the current row after scroll end and update the current index in your

```
currentIndex
```

object
Then allow view to scroll or not.
Make sure you have calculated  the cell width proper with left right edges also and cell space of collection view

```
var currentIndex = 0
var cellWidth = 0.0


func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let row = scrollView.contentOffset.x / cellWidth
            currentIndex = Int(row)
        }

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if scrollView.contentOffset.x < cellWidth * CGFloat(currentIndex){
            scrollView.contentOffset =  CGPoint(x: cellWidth * CGFloat(currentIndex), y: -20)
            scrollView.bounces = false
        } else {
            scrollView.bounces = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let indexPathOfVisible = collectionView.indexPath(for: collectionView.visibleCells.first ?? UICollectionViewCell())
    
    if indexPath.row < indexPathOfVisible?.row ?? 0 {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPathOfVisible!, at: .right, animated: false)
    } 
}
```